# How do i change in javascript date format like this-Mon Jun 07 2021 17:44:06 GMT+0300 (שעון ישראל (קיץ)) to 2021-06-07( in this order year/month/day)

Tags: javascript, date, date-format, date-formatting, react-dates

I have been trying to make somthing like this
const dateFormated = startDate.toLocaleDateString().split(".").join("-");

but it isn't in the right order and its missing numbers like instead being 06 its 6

Answer (score 1):

```
function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) 
        month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) 
        day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
}
 
console.log(formatDate('Sun May 11,2014'));
```